# Remove "Showing 1 to N of N Entries" Shiny DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

### Issue:

I'm looking to remove the showing 1 to n of n entries field in shiny DT. Please see picture below of what I would like to REMOVE.

Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: You should include an example.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `dom` option to determine which elements of the data table are shown. In the call to data table, you pass a named list of options to the `options` argument. `dom` accepts a character string where each element corresponds to one DOM element.

```
# only display the table, and nothing else
datatable(head(iris), options = list(dom = 't'))

# the filtering box and the table
datatable(head(iris), options = list(dom = 'ft'))
```

In your case, `i` is the table information summary: that's the one you want to leave out. You can also use this method to remove other elements like the search box or pagination controls.

See section 4.2 on this page for how to do this in R: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

This page in the Datatables manual discusses the DOM option: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 16):

You can pass the [info](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features#bInfo) option directly using `options`

```
 library(shiny)
 library(DT)
  ui <- fluidPage(
   dataTableOutput('myTable') 
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$myTable <- renderDataTable(mtcars, 
                                      options = list(pageLength = 15, info = FALSE)
                                      )
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```