# R Shiny data table hide the "Show Entries" label on top of the table but not dropdown box

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

please I have the following code to display a datatable:

```
fluidRow(column(3,
                dataTableOutput(outputId="table01", width = '100px')))
```

and this is how the rendered table is created:

```
output$table01 <- DT::renderDataTable({  
  df <- get_mp_data()
  if(is.null(df)){
        df <- data.frame()
  }else{
        upcolor = "lightblue"
        downcolor = "lightblue"
        col_name = "CHG"
        df <- datatable(df
                        , rownames = FALSE 
                        , caption = paste0("Pre/Post Duration")
                        , filter = 'none'
                        , options = list(scrollX = F
                                         #, lengthChange = FALSE  # this feature hides the "Show Entries" on top of the table, so we won't be able to customize how many entries we can see all together
                                         , pagingType = "numbers"  # this hides the Next and Previous buttons -->  https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType
                                        , autoWidth = T
                                        ,pageLength = 5 # this determines how many rows we want to see per page
                                        , info = FALSE #  this will hide the "Showing 1 of 2..." at the bottom of the table -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730816/remove-showing-1-to-n-of-n-entries-shiny-dt
                                        ,searching = FALSE  # this removes the search box  ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624413/remove-search-option-but-leave-search-columns-option
                                        ,columnDefs = list(list(width = '4', targets = c(3) ) 
                                                           ,list(width = '4', targets = c(2) )
                                                           )   # careful, column counting STARTS FROM 0 !
                                        )) %>% 
              formatStyle(col_name,
                          #background = styleColorBar(range(df[, c(col_name)]), 'lightblue'),
                          background = color_from_middle(df[, c(col_name)] , downcolor,   upcolor),
                          backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                          backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                          backgroundPosition = 'center')
  }
  return(df)
})
```

The problem with this code is that it shows "Show Entries" on the top left hand side of the table that takes a lot of useless space. I would like to only keep the dropdown and hide the text "Show Entries".
I couldn't find anything here # https://datatables.net/reference/option about this.
Notice how I don't want to use "lengthChange = FALSE" since this will also hide the dropdown box that allows to customize how many rows can be displayed all together.
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this option:

```
datatable(iris, options = list(
  language = list(lengthMenu = "_MENU_")
))
```