# How to add reactive object to secondary column header in output table?

Tags: html, r, shiny, transition, dt

I am working on a transition table module and am wrestling with how to make the output understandable for the user. I used to prepare transition tables in Excel; making the table legible was super easy but deriving the data for table output took hours. Now my problem is the opposite with R: takes a few seconds to generate the table output from millions of rows of data but table presentation is far from simple.

To start, I would like to reflect the user's "From" input (object `transFrom`) in this reactive table's secondary column header as shown in the image below; any suggestions for how to do this? I am completely clueless with respect to html. I had found this solution here [R Shiny app - Render Data Table with double header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079421/r-shiny-app-render-data-table-with-double-header), and I like it because it uses DT, which I use throughout (though I would have preferred the base R table, using Shiny `renderTable()`, but I could not make that work). I have researched this and found other packages for drafting nice tables but I am avoiding "package bloat" and would rather stick with base `R`, `Shiny`, `data.table`, and `DT` package IF POSSIBLE.

Note that the columns reflect the transition states FROM, and the rows reflect the transition states TO.

[image]

Here is the MWE code for actively rendering the above:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

# custom table container
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(colspan = 1, ''),
      th(colspan = 10, 'From state where initial period is =  ')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(colnames(results), th)
    )
  )
))


data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), # < left-align the table
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("results"),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
    setDT(x)
    unique_state <- unique(x$State)
    all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
    dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
                to_state = State[to]), 
            by = ID]
          [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
          [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
          to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
    )
  }
  
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data,input$transFrom,input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
    })

  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$results <- renderDT(server=FALSE,{
    results() %>% 
      datatable(rownames = FALSE,
                filter = 'none',
                container = sketch,
                options = list(scrollX = F
                               , dom = 'ft'
                               , lengthChange = T
                               , pagingType = "numbers"  # hides Next and Previous buttons
                               , autoWidth = T
                               , info = FALSE #  hide the "Showing 1 of 2..." at bottom of table
                               ,searching = FALSE  # removes search box
                          ),
                class = "display"
              )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `htmltools::withTags` doesn't play well with using shiny inputs (I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/issues/319)).

Please check the following:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}")), # < left-align the table
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  h4(strong("Transition table inputs:")),
  numericInput("transFrom", "From period:", 1, min = 1, max = 3),
  numericInput("transTo", "To period:", 2, min = 1, max = 3),
  h4(strong("Output transition table:")), 
  DTOutput("resultsDT"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- 
    reactive({
      results <- numTransit(data, input$transFrom, input$transTo) %>% 
        replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
        bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
      results <- cbind(results, Sum = rowSums(results[,-1]))
    })
  
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  output$resultsDT <- renderDT(server=FALSE, {
    req(results())
    datatable(
      data = results(),
      rownames = FALSE,
      filter = 'none',
      container = tags$table(
        class = 'display',
        tags$thead(
          tags$tr(
            tags$th(colspan = 1, ''),
            tags$th(colspan = 10, sprintf('From state where initial period is = %s', input$transFrom))
          ),
          tags$tr(
            lapply(colnames(results()), tags$th)
          )
        )
      ),
      options = list(scrollX = F
                     , dom = 'ft'
                     , lengthChange = T
                     , pagingType = "numbers"  # hides Next and Previous buttons
                     , autoWidth = T
                     , info = FALSE #  hide the "Showing 1 of 2..." at bottom of table
                     , searching = FALSE  # removes search box
      ),
      class = "display"
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Works very well, and I now see how html can be embedded in a reactive function in the server section.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 a more general way to send HTML from the server to the ui is using `renderUI` / `uiOutput`. However you should always prefer using *update* functions on existing html widgets if possible as it is faster than rerendering.